# python создать список состоящий из слов

Tags: python

Python, создать список состоящий из слов, если там есть слова в которых встречается буква "а" то эти слова заменить на пустые кавычки

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, какой именно список нужен, но пусть будет просто заранее заданный.

```
spisok = ['Слово', 'Каша', 'Андрей', 'Питон']
for word in spisok:
    if 'а' in word.lower():
        spisok[spisok.index(word)] = ''  # Меняем слово на пустую строку, если в нём есть буква "а", проходясь циклом по списку
print(spisok)
```